# different ":cl" package handling between Common Lisp implementations

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

**Why does this behavior happen?**
Additionally, is this an "implementation defined" disparity, or is one of these REPLs wrong?

*Please consider this Common Lisp code...*

```
(defpackage :new)
(in-package new)
(+ 2 2)
```

In CMUCL, this evaluates to the number four.

In SBCL, this returns returns an error:

```
; in: + 2
;     (NEW::+ 2 2)
;
; caught COMMON-LISP:STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: NEW::+
;
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     +
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a COMMON-LISP:UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1000508083}>:
  The function NEW::+ is undefined.
```

However, SBCL will call "+" correctly when it is evaluated as

`(cl:+ 2 2)`

and CMUCL works with this as well.

When I looked in the HyperSpec, I couldn't find a clear section that addressed this context. The closest I could find was this: [Section 11.1.2.2 The COMMON-LISP-USER Package](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abb.htm). Which leads me to believe that SBCL has the right interpretation; that "NEW" didn't inherit symbols from "COMMON-LISP" so therefore the entire Common Lisp language isn't accessible from within "NEW". **But** it's really strange that three lines would kill the entire language so I'm still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify packages from which to inherit symbols in `defpackage` with `:use`, or you can call `use-package` to the same end; I usually do it in `defpackage`. I wasn't aware that CMUCL behaved differently than SBCL in this regard, but I always include `(:use :common-lisp)` in my packages. The Common Lisp HyperSpec `defpackage` documentation says: [If `:use` is not supplied, it defaults to the same implementation-dependent value as the `:use` argument to `make-package`.](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpkg.htm) Here you can see a difference between CMUCL and SBCL:

CMUCL

---

```
CL-USER> ;; CMUCL
; No value
CL-USER> (defpackage :new)
#<The NEW package, 0/9 internal, 0/2 external>
CL-USER> (package-use-list :new)
(#<The COMMON-LISP package, 0/6 internal, 978/1227 external>)
```

SBCL

---

```
CL-USER> ;; SBCL
; No value
CL-USER> (defpackage :new)
#<PACKAGE "NEW">
CL-USER> (package-use-list :new)
NIL
```

The `package-use-list` function shows that the `new` package is using `common-lisp` in CMUCL, but not in SBCL. You can avoid such issues by explicitly `use`ing packages:

```
CL-USER> (defpackage :new (:use :common-lisp))
#<PACKAGE "NEW">
CL-USER> (package-use-list :new)
(#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP">)
CL-USER> (in-package :new)
#<PACKAGE "NEW">
NEW> (+ 2 2)
4
```

It would be typical in a file to use `:export` in the `defpackage` form to export symbols, but from the REPL in the `new` package you can also define functions and export their symbols for use in other packages:

```
NEW> (defun add3 (x) (+ x 3))
ADD3
NEW> (export 'add3)
T
```

Then go back to the main workspace, the `common-lisp-user` package, and call `use-package` to access the new function:

```
NEW> (in-package :cl-user)
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
CL-USER> (use-package :new)
T
CL-USER> (add3 4)
7
```

Comment: If my memory is correct (and it probably isn't), the reason SBCL shifted was that it was surprising to people that the use of package `:cl` no longer worked once you started specifying other packages with `:use-package`.

Answer (score 3):

It's undefined in the CL standard which packages to *use* when there is no `:use` clause in DEFPACKAGE.

CLHS: [DEFPACKAGE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpkg.htm#defpackage):

> The arguments to :use set the packages that the package named by package-name will inherit from. If :use is not supplied, it defaults to the same **implementation-dependent value** as the :use argument to make-package.

SBCL chose not to *use* any package then.

Traditionally other CL implementation usually choose to *use* the CL package plus some packages of extension. The intention then was that a new package is by default *useful* for Lisp programming like the package `CL-USER`.

For portable code you need to specify which packages a package should *use*. Usually `defpackage` and `make-package` are the operators to look at.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addendum to the other answers.

One thing that I have done in the past is to write a macro like this:

```
(defvar *user-package-use-list*
  (package-use-list (find-package ':common-lisp-user)))

(defmacro define-user-package (name &body options)
  `(defpackage ,name
     (:use ,@(mapcar #'package-name *user-package-use-list*))
     ,@options))
```

Using this then

```
(define-user-package :my-user-package)
```

Will define a package which is 'like' `CL-USER` in the sense that it uses all the same packages, and it will do this in a way which works across implementations.